How to analyze/debug HTTP Digest authentication issues? Tools or test servers available?
I have written a server monitoring tool which I need to extend so that it also supports HTTP Digest authentication. Doing so I strictly followed the RFC-2617 specs. To test that new extension I am firing test requests at the only openly available test server using Digest authentication that I found, namely https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Digest/.
However, I am unable to get a successful "your browser made it"-response from the Jigsaw-server when sending requests from my tool even though it seems to generate proper authorization headers.
I say "seems" because the issue with Digest authentication is that the initial server response on connection setup contains a 'nonce' which the client then needs to correctly integrate into an Authorization-header that gets embedded in the response. Due to this one can not replay such request-/response-sequences with different clients (which is the purpose of the Digest authentication but of course makes it very difficult to test and compare the respective input and output).
What I did to verify my tool's implementation, though, was to capture and decode (using Wireshark) requests and responses that I did with misc. browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Brave) which had worked fine. I then compared these traces with my tool's responses and they looked OK (module those 'nonce'- and 'response'-values of course). I also fed several of the captured 'nonce'-s to my tool and it generated responses that contained the correct (i.e. the identical) Authorization-header that the respective browser had generated for the captured request. Other test-cases that I had used were given in the RFC-2617 specs and in the excellent Wikipedia-description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication.
I am thus pretty sure by now that the issue is not with a faulty Authorization-header but in some other difference of behaviour. My problem is: I have no idea, what that relevant difference could be.
Example from a request/challenge/response-sequence captured using Wireshark:

The client sends a GET-response to https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Digest/

Server responses with an HTTP 401 response containing the header:
www-authenticate: Digest realm="test", domain="/HTTP/Digest", nonce="1be0167f214fa00d5d7999110740d824", stale=true

The client then need to include this header in its 2nd GET response:
Authorization: Digest username="guest", realm="test", nonce="1be0167f214fa00d5d7999110740d824", uri="/HTTP/Digest/", response="f3378661fc3497a903b5bf9d1966cafa"

Server responds with a 200 response containing HTML content which displays a "Your browser made it!"- success message.


My tool generates exactly that Authorization-header string as in step 3 (when I inject the extracted nonce from the challenge in step 2) but when I direct it to that website directly I always end up with a 401 You are denied access to this resource.-response. :-(
Anyone with experience in Digest authentication who could share some experience or caveats here?
Or any idea anyone how else one could verify and debug this? Are there other Digest authentication test servers available anywhere that might emit a bit more informations or details as to why a received Digest authentication request is not acceptable?

I can't help with this subject matter, unfortunately, but l do see that RFC 2617 was replaced by RFC 7616. Not sure if there are any differences there that are relevant to your question.

@Kevin Christopher Henry thanks for the hint and link! I hadn't been aware of that. I have now implemented that newer RFC as well (Caveat: there are a couple of errors in that RFC - make sure to check https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/rfc7616. Only after incorporating the corrections listed there all my testcases ran green). Unfortunately that didn't solve my original problem, i.e. my monitoring tool can still not log automatically into that Jigsaw Digest test site. :-(
